# Save sklearn classifier fit by cross_val

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got a classifier I'm fitting using a cross_val and getting good results. Essentially all I'm doing is:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight="balanced")
scores = cross_val_score(clf, data, target, cv=8)
predict_RF = cross_val_predict(clf, data, target, cv=8)

from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'churnModel.pkl')
```

Essentially what I want to do is take the model that's getting fit by cross_val and export to joblib. However when I try to pull it in in a separate project I get:

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the model.
```

So I'm guessing cross_val is not actually saving the fit to my clf? How do I persist the model fit that cross_val is generating?

Comment: Which model? When you cross validate, you fit *several* models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

juanpa.arrivillaga is right. I am afraid you would have to do it manually, but scikit-learn makes it quite easy. The cross_val_score create trained models that are not returned to you. Below you would have the trained models in a list (i.e. clf_models)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from copy import deepcopy

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=8)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight="balanced")
clf_models = []

# keep in mind your X and y should be indexed same here
kf.get_n_splits(X_data)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_data, y_data):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X_data[train_index], X_data[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y_data[train_index], y_data[test_index]
    tmp_clf = deepcopy(clf)
    tmp_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Got a score of {}".format(tmp_clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
    clf_models.append(tmp_clf)
```

-edit via juanpa.arrivillaga's advice
StratifiedKFold is a better choice. Here I selected just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Probably better to use `StratifiedKFold`

Comment: So if i understand correctly, clf_models is a list of 8 models fitted to a subset of the parent data right? Is there best practice for getting this to a single model? Do I just pick the one with the highest score or is there a way to blend them?

Comment: That is correct, clf_models is a list of 8 fitted models. If you are using cross-validation, the purpose is usually to finding good hyper-parameters for a model. Selecting the model with the best score might be the right choice if it means that the fold in the data that the model didn't train on was particularly not representative of the dataset in the future. You should look into if this is true. These things are usually decided on a case by case basis; RandomForestClassifier might not even yield any results for your case. In short, it depends.